# Converting DropZone.files to HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone.js in my angularjs and .net application to upload files. `dropzone.files` has the uploaded files, I have my own custom angularjs method where I take the `Base64String` from the `dropzone.files` and send that string to server and convert that string to `Image`. Its working fine for images but not with other file types like .docx or pdf. I am basically trying to send `dropzone.files` to my server and have them converted to `HttpPostedFileBase`. How do I achieve this?

here is my angularjs controller:-

```
$scope.create = function () {
    MyService.create($scope.viewModel, $scope.dropzone.files, function () {
        alert.success("success");
    });
};
```

here is my c# controller:-

```
[HttpPost]
[AuthenticationFilter(Disabled = true)]
public JsonResult Create(string data, string file)
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(file.Remove(0, 23))))
    {
        Image image = Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
        image.Save(Server.MapPath("~/images/im111.jpeg"));
    }
}
```

Comment: dropzone function asks for a url which gets hit after selecting files in dropzone..........and in that case you get all dropzone files in C#

Comment: @Shubham yes I know of the default behavior but that is making a call to the server for every file but I would rather make only one call to the server with all the files attached